# Wordpress site pages returns 404 error

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I made one site using WordPress that is working fine on my local machine but when I hosted the same WordPress files and database into server only the home page is working.

Other links return `404 resource not found` error. As per my knowledge, the error is because of the page permalinks, those are static links.

Comment: How did you move the site to the host? What kind of host is it? How are your links set up, what do they look like? What have you done to diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hello ganesh Here you need to update your Permalink.
Go  Dashboard ->  Settings -> Permalink 
and click on "save change" button at bottom.

Prefer this link:  http://prntscr.com/jxz3cm

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following statement.

1. When you upload on the server, you have to change the website link
   in the database table wp-option.
2. Login to the WP admin panel, go to setting> Permalinks and just
   click "Save Changes" button.
3. Install the plugin "[Search Regex](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/)" and find the localhost URL
   and replace with the website URL.

Comment: anyother way to change the localhost url

Comment: @ganesh Another way is, you have to find the URL inside all of the post content and widgets. It means everywhere the whole website. That's why try to use "Search Regex" plugin.

Answer (score 0):

login to admin dashboard  in settings => permalinks => click on button save change